# Criterion for factorability of cubic polynomials

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

It is well-known that, over an arbitrary field $k$, a quadratic polynomial $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ with $a,b,c \in k$ factorises over $k$ if and only if its discriminant, $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$, is a square in $k$. From an algorithmic standpoint, checking that $\Delta$ is a square is much faster than checking that the polynomial $f(x)$ factorises (especially when you have a whole bunch of polynomials to attempt to factor).

Was wondering if there is a similar condition that can be found for cubic polynomials. Namely, a cubic polynomial $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ if and only if *some condition holds*. I know that when $k = \mathbb{R}$, there is a simple criterion again involving the discriminant of the cubic polynomial. However, a bit like in the quadratic setting, would like a more general criterion that applies to any field (including when $k = \mathbb{Q}$). This general condition is proving a little elusive for me to find.

If anyone has any suggestions for this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If a cubic polynomial is irreducible in $K[x]$, then it cannot be factored further. It is known that
a cubic polynomial is irreducible in $K[x]$ if and only if it has no root over $K$. We can test this, for example, for $K=\Bbb Q$ by the Rational Root Test. Over $\Bbb R$ a cubic has always a real root, so it factorizes into a linear factor and a quadratic factor (which you have studied before, and which may factor further).

Edit: It is easy to see that the cubic polynomial from the comments,
$$
47x^3-1222x^2-3928x+209664
$$
is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$, since it is already irreducible over $\Bbb F_5$, which is easy to see (it has no root there).

Comment: Very true, but the rational root test is not necessarily the most practical method to test for factorability if the number of factors of $a$ and $d$ is large. Unless I'm mistaken I don't this method will be better than straight up factoring it as the polynomial.

Comment: Right, but often the polynomial has small coefficients (like in all exercises), like $f=x^3 - 9x^2 + 20x - 12$. Then we see quickly (also without the rational root test) if there is a rational root. In the same way I could say, I rarely use the $\Delta$ for finding a rational root of a quadratic equation.

Comment: I think my point is very specific to the circumstances I find myself in whereby I want to find the most efficient algorithm to testing factoring of such cubic polynomials that could have large coefficients or large numbers of factors. I could apply the rational root test to factor quadratic polynomials in the exact same way you mentioned but I've found that doing a discriminant computation is more effective (especially for the sorts of polynomials I'm encountering). Not only does the discriminant idea work for factoring quadratics but it is also quite effective at factoring certain quartics

Comment: I don't want to discredit your suggestion since for degree 3 polynomials it is a very very good option. I just want to see if there's a better and potentially more algorithmically friendly option

Comment: I see. In this case, you should add a typical example with large coefficients to your post, and explain where they come from. This will help to provide more context for your question. I was expecting the typical exercise cubic polynomials.

Comment: Sure thing, here is one example of a polynomial I want to factor is: $47x^3 - 1222x^2 - 3928x + 209664$. For this one, if one wishes to use the rational root test to factor it, then there would be around 216 checks that need to be done and I reckon that'll be costly compared to factoring it directly as a polynomial (especially if one does the test over a huge number of iterations). Correct me is you think I'm wrong about this

Comment: For the sake of comparison with quadratic polynomials (which I motivated), I could do a rational root test to test reducibility (with maybe 200ish checks to do) or do a single computation with the discriminant to see whether it can be factored. Naturally the latter proves to me more effective

Comment: For your example, it is trivial to check that it has no root over the field $\Bbb F_5$, so it is irreducible also over $\Bbb Z$, and hence also over $\Bbb Q$ ( I have edited my answer).

Comment: Will a good graphing software provide an idea about the roots?

Comment: @DietrichBurde that's a very neat observation which I've overlooked and could work particularly well for degree $3$ polynomials since you'd just need to check the roots over $\mathbb{F}_p$. So a general strategy to test whether an arbitrary polynomial $f$ is irreducible over the rationals could be the following. Take a set of small primes $p$ (up to some threshold bound say 30 maybe) and test whether, for at least one of these primes, $f$ has a root over $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Comment: Small remark: this is won't necessarily give a deterministic answer to the question of whether the polynomial factors, but if an answer is not ascertained from this then one can use RRT or straight up factoring to accurately determine whether it actually factors. At the very least I reckon this could be a bit faster than the other methods :)